# amazon AWS endpoint URL displays differently than opening file locally, where to start?

Tags: css, google-chrome, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localhost

I am building a website.

1. I built it locally, it works both in Chrome and in Firefox (when navigating the files locally)
2. I uploaded the files to amazon s3

and here's where I get some funky behavior.

if I use the amazon endpoint url to access the site:
   it doesn't display properly in chrome, but it does in firefox. (what I mean by doesn't display properly is that parts of my css aren't being loaded in chrome, but they are being loaded in firefox)

if i navigate the local files on my machine:
   it works just fine in both chrome and firefox. Everything is displayed perfectly fine and all of the css gets pulled in and rendered.

I guess what I'm curious about is, would behavior like this be an issue with Chrome or with Amazon AWS?

If parts of my css aren't even being pulled in by chrome (as in, when I open the developer tools, the css lines don't appear and I just get the default css associated with  tags), it seems like this would be an issue with either chrome or AWS.

but when I use navigate the files locally in chrome, everything works just fine. So now I can eliminate Chrome as the culprit and point the finger at AWS.

But then when I use the aws endpoint in Firefox, it works just fine again...

So AWS isn't to blame either?

Im just curious why I'm getting different behavior based on how i choose to open the files, even though the files are the same both locally and on amason s3

UPDATE: So I sent an invalidation through cloudfront distribution.
Now when I visit the domain that I own and run the site off of, everything works both in chrome and firefox.

But the Amazon AWS Endpoint is still displaying improperly in Chrome despite the fact that the regular domain works... In the end, nothing is broken when the end user visits the site or when I edit the site locally, so it seems that the amazon endpoint is to blame.

If anyone has any ideas, now I'm just curious what the hell is happening inside of AWS

Comment: What "endpoint" are you using -- `s3.amazonaws.com`, `s3-website.amazonaws.com` or `cloudfront.net`? If you open the Developer Console in the non-functioning web browser, are any error messages displayed? Can you point us to the website to help diagnose?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using thes3 endpoint. (broken link) http://www.zacharyjcohan.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com that is the Endpoint URL, where things aren't quite working properly
www.zacharyjcohan.com is the link where everything works. The actual issue is the spacing between the github/linked in logos. They should have some space around them (using flexbox layout and justifying the content to be space-around). But youll notice on the enpoint url, the logos get centered and are right next to each other

Comment: Both of those links look identical to me (Mac Chrome and Mac Safari).

Comment: interesting.. well at least i know that everything is working on the mac side of things. I have a windows machine. Either way, thank you for your time and effort, it is appreciated.